# Undefined for a Select List when used in ngForm

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select, bootstrap-4

I'm an Angular beginner and I'm trying to print values of form elements selected in console. Every other element like got printed but the `select` selected list element shows `undefined`. Here's my code
**category.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getCategories(){
    return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges()
      }
}
```

**product-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/category.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-forum',
  templateUrl: './product-forum.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-forum.component.css']
})
export class ProductForumComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$
  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$=categoryService.getCategories()
   }

  save(product){
    console.log(product)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**product-form.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input ngModel name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input ngModel name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
                    {{ c.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
            <input ngModel name="image" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

[image: AddProductPage]

After I hit **SAVE** button,

**CONSOLE**

```
{title: "title", price: 10, category: "undefined", image: "imageUrl"}
category: "undefined"
image: "imageUrl"
price: 10
title: "title"
__proto__: Object
```

**CATEGORIES**
[image: Categories Json Data]

Comment: how is your categories$ array looks like?

Comment: Hey! I've updated post with Categories data

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngValue` instead `value` as follows.

```
  <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [ngValue]="c.name">
        {{ c.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: can you add your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58936980?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

try this replace c.$key with c.name or just c. it should work. if not please share your sample JSON.

```
 <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [ngValue]="c.name">
                {{ c.name }}
            </option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="category" ngModel id="category" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.name">
        {{ c.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes